# Is there a way to add categories to each date in a SQL query?

Tags: sql

I have a date table - which I can query for each day in the month.  I need to add 4 categories to each date - so a 30-day table becomes a 120-row table with each day having 4 categories.  The categories are pre-defined and do change from time to time - but generally stay the same.

I would like to have each day in each month have a row for that day + that category.

```
SELECT 
    cm.date_format, 
    ' ' AS 'DC', 
    ' ' AS 'SALES_ORG_ID', 
    ' ' AS 'SALES_ORG_DESC', 
    ' ' AS 'COUNTRY', 
    ' ' AS 'ORDER_CLASSIFICATION'
FROM 
    NAM_ANALYTICS.CALENDAR_MDV cm 
WHERE 
    cm.DATE_ID BETWEEN 20231101 AND 20231130
ORDER BY 
    cm.DATE_ID ASC
```

Comment: Your question's not very clear. What DBMS are you using? What have you tried? Can you please include the schema of the tables you're expecting to be in your query? From the sounds of it, you're probably looking for [`CROSS JOIN`](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_join_cross.asp), but I can't say for sure without more details.

Answer (score 0):

I think this query can works for you, let me know if you need any more details on it.

```
SELECT 
    cm.date_format, 
    category.category_name AS 'DC', 
    ' ' AS 'SALES_ORG_ID', 
    ' ' AS 'SALES_ORG_DESC', 
    ' ' AS 'COUNTRY', 
    ' ' AS 'ORDER_CLASSIFICATION'
FROM 
    NAM_ANALYTICS.CALENDAR_MDV cm 
CROSS JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 'Category1' AS category_name
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'Category2' AS category_name
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'Category3' AS category_name
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'Category4' AS category_name
    ) category
WHERE 
    cm.DATE_ID BETWEEN 20231101 AND 20231130
ORDER BY 
    cm.DATE_ID ASC, category.category_name ASC;
```